# Move Processed Files to a Year, Month, Day Folder Tree Backup Folder ( SSIS )

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package which has a Foreach File Enumerator Loop and the last task is to Rename and Move the file to a Backup Directory once processed. This is OK but I would like the Rename and Move task to still Rename but now Move the file into a Backup directory structured Year, Month, Day and dynamically create the directories if they aren't there.

I.e.

```
....Backup\2020\10\19\Processed_20201019_160251.csv
....Backup\2020\11\20\Processed_20201120_161751.csv
```

Hope this makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSIS Expressions to determine day/month/year:

```
Day: DATEPART("dd", GETDATE()) 
Year: DATEPART("yyyy", GETDATE()) 
Month: DATEPART("mm", GETDATE())
```

Then construct a path with the above information in another SSIS expression:

```
"Backup\"+@[User::Current_Year]+"\"+@[User::Current_Month]+"\"+@[User::Current_Day]+"\"+@[User::File_Name]+"."+@[User::File_Extension]
```